# Explicit C++ Macro Expansion

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, expand

I want to make all logging functions include the file and line, thus I need a macro for it.
The macro is defined in the following manner:

```
 inline void _internLogFunc(int line, const char* function, const char* data ...)
    {...}

    #define _InternLogParams(...) _internLogFunc(__LINE__, __FUNC__, __VA_ARGS__)

    #define Log(...) _InternLogParams(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The problem is that when the function is called in the following manner:

```
 Log("[Version]: "
    #if defined(_RELEASE)
                "RELEASE "
    #elif defined(_PROFILE)
                "PROFILE "
    #else
                "DEBUG "
    #endif

    #if defined(PURE_CLIENT)
                "PURE CLIENT"
    #elif (DEDICATED_SERVER)
                "DEDICATED SERVER"
    #else
                "DEVELOPMENT BUILD"
    #endif
                );
```

The macros expand to the following:

```
> _internLogFunc(950,  
>                __FUNCTION__  , 
>                "[Version]: " 
>                #if defined(_RELEASE) "RELEASE "
>                #elif defined(_PROFILE) "PROFILE " 
>                #else "DEBUG " 
>                #endif 
>                #if defined(PURE_CLIENT) "PURE CLIENT" 
>                #elif (DEDICATED_SERVER) "DEDICATED SERVER" 
>                #else "DEVELOPMENT BUILD" 
>                #endif);
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could make the macros given as argument expand first?

Comment: Put all of the `#ifdef` statements outside of the parameter declarations and use further #defines there for the `"DEBUG"` ``"RELEASE"`` literals etc.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible, you can't have preprocessor conditional statements inside a preprocessor macro call like that.

Comment: I'd prefer not to change the calls to the functions, since I would like to redirect all calls of the original logging function through my own, the purpose would be to make such a case possible.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, why would it not be possible ? Shouldn't the inner macro be expanded first, and then the outer macro ? just like function parameters ?

Comment: While the preprocessor these days is an integrated part of the compiler, it's still a separate step before the compiler parsing, and uses its own (unrelated to C++) language. The preprocessor simply doesn't work the way you want to. If you want preprocessor conditional compilation like you show, then you have to make `Log` a real C++ function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Log(...) macro takes variable arguments, and the call to it is parsed by the pre-processor. It'll take everything it sees in the braces and pass it as a VA_ARG.

I suspect it might be a limitation of using the ellipsis in the pre-processor.

Write the Log() function in C++ to avoid the pre-processor parsing that way, or use macros outside of the Log() call to build the string you want to output.

For instance:

```
#if defined(_RELEASE)
#define DS1 "RELEASE "    
#elif defined(_PROFILE)
#define DS1 "PROFILE "
#else
#define DS1 "DEBUG "
#endif

#if defined(PURE_CLIENT)
#define DS2 "PURE CLIENT"
#elif defined (DEDICATED_SERVbER)
#define DS2 "DEDICATED SERVER"
#else
#define DS2 "DEVELOPMENT BUILD"
#endif

#define DEBUG_STRING "[Version]: " DS1 DS2


Log(DEBUG_STRING, "Extra1", "extra2");
```

Answer (score 4):

just put all the `#ifedf`s outside the function call and use them to define some literal strings.
Example:

```
#ifdef _RELEASE 
#define VERSION "RELEASE"
#else 
#define VERSION "DEBUG"
#endif

...

LOG(VERSION);    

...
```